# Create objects, EACH with unique ids using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

So I'm trying to generate an array that will have multiple objects, one of them with another array. Each object should have its own unique id, but when using for loop, each batch has objects with the same repeated ids. using i variable or even adding random number value seems to be not working. Is this even achievable in javascript?

Test.js

```
const testFunc = () => {
  let resultArray = []
  let testObj = {}
  let testArray = []

  const rn = () => {
    return ~~(Math.random() * 1000)
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    testObj = { id: rn() }
    testArray.push(testObj)
    testObj = {}
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    resultArray.push(testArray)
  }

  console.log(resultArray)
  return resultArray
}
```

Expected result:

```
[
  [
    { id: 859, text: 0 },
    { id: 232, text: 1 },
    { id: 240, text: 2 },
    { id: 638, text: 3 },
    { id: 393, text: 4 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 681, text: 0 },
    { id: 384, text: 1 },
    { id: 413, text: 2 },
    { id: 721, text: 3 },
    { id: 985, text: 4 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 348, text: 0 },
    { id: 911, text: 1 },
    { id: 255, text: 2 },
    { id: 816, text: 3 },
    { id: 797, text: 4 }
  ]
]
```

Result I get:

```
[
  [
    { id: 859, text: 0 },
    { id: 232, text: 1 },
    { id: 240, text: 2 },
    { id: 638, text: 3 },
    { id: 393, text: 4 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 859, text: 0 },
    { id: 232, text: 1 },
    { id: 240, text: 2 },
    { id: 638, text: 3 },
    { id: 393, text: 4 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 859, text: 0 },
    { id: 232, text: 1 },
    { id: 240, text: 2 },
    { id: 638, text: 3 },
    { id: 393, text: 4 }
  ]
]
```

Comment: You'll have a lot of trouble with id collisions if you're picking a random number from 0 to 999. It's called the birthday paradox. In your case, you only need 38 items before you have 50% chance of having 2 of the same ids.Either keep a counter, or use uuid()  from the npm uuid package.

Comment: @CharlesBamford Thanks for the comment! I tried uuid() as well, but the result was exactly the same - except that it's not in numbers only.

Comment: That's because of the problems the answers solve.

Answer (score 1):

You push the `testArray` thrice to the `resultArray`. Instead generate `testArray` in a loop, push it to the `resultArray`, and add the items:

```js
const testFunc = () => {
  const resultArray = []

  const rn = () => {
    return ~~(Math.random() * 1000)
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const testArray = []
    resultArray.push(testArray)
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      const testObj = { id: rn() }
      testArray.push(testObj)
    }
  }

  return resultArray
}

console.log(testFunc())
```

Comment: So I was just pushing three identical items. No wonder they all have the same ids. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever creating a single sub-array. The line

```
let testArray = []
```

only runs once, and you do

```
resultArray.push(testArray)
```

3 times - so in the result, all sub-arrays in `resultArray` refer to the same `testArray`.

Create a new array explicitly instead, and use a nested loop so that there are 3x3 iterations total:

```js
let resultArray = []
let testObj = {}

const rn = () => {
  return ~~(Math.random() * 1000)
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const testArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const testObj = {
      id: rn()
    }
    testArray.push(testObj)
  }
  resultArray.push(testArray)
}


console.log(resultArray)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Your explanation cleared my head a lot